# Sum of $\frac1{\sqrt1+\sqrt3}+\frac1{\sqrt5+\sqrt7}+...+\frac1{\sqrt{9997}+\sqrt{9999}}>24$

Tags: inequality, radicals

> Prove the following inequality.
>   $\frac1{\sqrt1+\sqrt3}+\frac1{\sqrt5+\sqrt7}+...+\frac1{\sqrt{9997}+\sqrt{9999}}>24$

I tried to rationalizing the denominator and I got the following inequality to be proved,

$$-\sqrt1+\sqrt3-\sqrt5+\sqrt7-...-\sqrt{9997}+\sqrt{9999}>48$$

Once I got that, I don't know what to do with the LHS. Hints or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/609151/42969 – both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt1%2B%5Csqrt3%7D%2B%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt5%2B%5Csqrt7%7D%2B...%2B%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt%7B9997%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7B9999%7D%7D%3E24%24&p=1)

Comment: Julien's answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609151/ is my favorite.